# What is the purpose of the [runonuithread] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I just see one question where OP used the [runonuithread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/runonuithread). In the tag wiki I see there is no meaningfully wiki description for what it is for and seems useless tag.

**Current Description:**

> There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!
>
> Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its usage.
>
> All registered users may propose new tag wikis.
>
> (Note that if you have less than 20000 reputation, your tag wiki will be peer reviewed before it is published.)

IMO, this should be deleted because if you think it should persist then guys will create tag of all `android` function later. This `runonuithread` is basically method in android.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the 69 questions have the tag removed. There are now no questions with that tag. The tag will be removed at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: I thought about removing some of them when I saw this question as I agree it doesn't need to be a tag. But, I haven't seen the "rules" on that. If we think it's worth doing just do it or should we have some kind of consensus?

Comment: In general I agree with that. For this one I was pretty sure that it was such a specific language feature that I felt it was save to move on ASAP, also because I saw it appear on C# wpf questions which would turn it in an huge mis-used, mis-understand tag. Remember that a high-rep user always can re-create that tag if there is need for.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So basically if I feel confident enough, like this one, then I should just delete it out of all of the questions, right?

Comment: If the request get upvotes and no comments I would say yes. Maybe I was a little bit quick on this...When in doubt you can always try to contact some high-rep users in the tag (for example in chat).

Comment: I do mostly Android and I agree it was the right thing to do. I was just trying to clear up when it was ok to do. Thanks, I think you answered my question.